# About Kolmogorov's probability definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the definition of probability (Kolmogorov) on Wikipedia, the assumption of $σ$-additivity is stated as:

If we have a countable sequence of mutually exclusive events $A_i$ $\implies P(U_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)$

My question is about the $\infty$ notation:

Do we also include property for the finite countable sequences this way? (meaning it can be derived in some way from the property for infinitely countable? If so then how do we prove this?). Or is it meant but not stated explicitly using $P(U_{i=1}^{N} A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N P(A_i)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implicitly included. If you have a finite sequence $A = (A_1, \ldots, A_N)$ you can extend it to an infinite sequence by $\hat A = (A_1, \ldots, A_N, \emptyset, \emptyset, \ldots)$ or, formally,
$$
\hat A_i = \begin{cases} A_i &\text{if }i \leq n\\\emptyset&\text{else.}\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^N A_i\right) = P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty \hat A_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(\hat A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N P(A_i).
$$